Efficiently backing up a Windows 11 boot partition that will change size
To avoid an XY problem, please allow me to directly state the goal: To be able to easily back up a Windows 11 NTFS system partition and have that partition and those backups take up as little space as possible.
That Windows 11 partition is rarely used (Linux is primarily used), but is used once in a while.  The partition is currently 200GB with 80GB used.  The storage media is a much larger SSD.
My first inclination is to use Clonezilla.  Clonezilla can easily backup the Windows and Linux partitions, as well as all the other partitions.
But Clonezilla has a serious drawback: Clonezilla does not support restoring a larger partition to a smaller partition, even if it would fit (IOW, restoring that 200GB partition with 80GB used to a 150GB partition is not supported).
Clonezilla also doesn't directly support restoring a smaller partition to a larger partition, but this can reportedly be worked around with a couple command line parameters (it's supposed to work, but it's a workaround, so there could be risk involved).
This brings us back to the goal: keeping a Windows 11 system partition as small as reasonably possible and having the backups take up as little space as possible.  Here is the current plan:

shrink the Windows 11 partition to as small as Windows 11 will tolerate (and still work fine)
backup the partition using Clonezilla as needed
when Windows 11 needs more space (perhaps due to a large Windows Update patch), increase the size of the Windows 11 partition as required
backup the partition using Clonezilla as needed

Is there a better way to do this?
As part of this plan, to allow the Windows 11 partition to be expanded in the future, will it be best to create an unused partition immediately following it (logically) on the SSD?  For HDDs, this would be needed (else the Windows 11 partition would not be expandable), but I'm not sure if this is needed with modern SSDs.

I want to say - and its been a while, that clonezilla won't backup unused space. I'm half certain I've done recovery to a smaller drive (slightly) as well.

@JourneymanGeek Correct, by default it won't backup unused space.  And your comment makes me aware that I left out a key phrase in my question.  It was obvious in my head, but that doesn't help others help me!  Edit forthcoming...

@JourneymanGeek I can't believe I left that out.  So obvious to me, and so not obvious to anyone reading what I wrote.  Thanks for pointing it out, even if inadvertently doing so!  Does the edit I made now result in the question making sense (without the simple edit, it must have caused a couple heads to scratch... fortunately, only a few people read it).

My choice would be commercial, free, software that can run on Windows while mounted, using VSS, such as Macrium Reflect Free, https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/macrium_reflect_free_edition.html, that offers compression and can ignore empty space.

Of note, a Windows 11 NTFS boot partition is incorrect, the boot partition is the (FAT32) ESP (no exceptions because Windows 11 supports UEFI mode ONLY).

@ChanganAuto You're absolutely right, and I want to word that better.  What is the correct wording to express that it's not just some partition containing Windows 11 executable application files, but actually contains the bootable OS, yet is not the boot partition itself?

@DrMoishePippik Thanks for the recommendation.  I thought about using Macrium Reflect Free, as I have quite a bit of experience with it.  The reasons I didn't make it my first choice were twofold: (1) I thought Macrium stopped updating the free version several years ago (I'm not even seeing it on their website any more... do you?), although MG seems to have a newer version (but I would never download an app from anywhere but the source) (2) I want to use the same tool to backup Windows, Linux, & other partitions, and Macrium seems very Windows-centric.  Your thoughts?  (chat if many thoughts!)

Windows - the Windows installer - creates several partitions when installed in a blank drive but typically you'd need only the ESP and the system partition (popularly know as the "C:\ drive"). For better, assured, results you should clone everything including one "reserved" (shown in the answer below) and "recovery".

@ChanganAuto Based on your comment, I'll edit my question to use the word "system" partition instead of "boot" partition.  Thanks.  That's the word I needed.

@EndAntisemiticHate, yes, the truly free (for non-commercial use) Reflect's last version is 8.0.7783. Though Macrium has hidden that. Major Geek's claims it is an  "Official Mirror for Macrium Reflect FREE Edition." That has been my most recent source for home use, which I checked at VirusTotal.  That said, if it's for commercial use, or you consider it risky, there are a plethora of Windows imaging tools:  https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/ . As much as I like Linux, Windows' VSS allows imaging an entire mounted drive, which Linux does not.

@DrMoishePippik I think I still have Macrium Reflect Free from when I downloaded it directly from Macrium (hopefully the latest release they offered).  If you're ever concerned about what you have, I can generate a hash of mine so you can compare the hashes.

First, Clonezilla can restore to a larger disk and I have done it dozens of times. I allowed Conezilla to complete just copying the data with the existing partition sizes. Then you just use a partition tool, gparted for example, to move or resize the partition to consume the unused free space.  This has never corrupted a drive for me.  Starting with Windows 10, the disk management tool can expand some partitions.
As far as restoring to a smaller disk, I have done this before also.  I started with gparted to shrink the partition down. In your case, I wouldn't go much below 90GB because reallocations will probably take a long time.
Once you are done resizing the partition with gparted, Clonezilla or any other cloning tool can clone the data over.
Clonezilla can backup your disk using the "disk to image" option and then you can choose one of several compression techniques to compress the data.
Also, in Windows 10 and above, the "Disk Management" tool will allow you to expand some partitions while the OS is running.

There are definite limits on what Windows can do since the OS is actively running.  Shrinking will not move any data, unlike gparted, so if a single cluster is used 10GB away from the nearest data, Windows will not allow you to shrink it that small.

Thank you for your helpful answer. It's good to hear that you've had so many positive experiences restoring to a larger partition with Clonezilla. If I'm reading what you wrote correctly, what you mentioned about restoring to a smaller partition, however, seems contrary to the Clonezilla documentation and what many others have written about Clonezilla. Are you sure about that? It seems possible using to force it to do so using some workarounds, but some people express reliability concerns about doing so.

I think what OP means is shrink it first then backup. Though a backup before shrinking isn't a bad idea either

@EndAntisemiticHate  The key is to shrink the partition with gparted BEFORE you using clonezilla.  Clonezilla can not copy a larger partition to a smaller drive as is, but with the help of gparted.

Also note above the Disk management tool has the option to Shrink a partition, but it will limit how much you shrink it.  If a single cluster is in use in the middle of the free space that you won't be able to reduce it any further than that cluster.  A defragmentation program that has the option to do a consolidation defragment could help with this type of issue, but I find its faster to just use gparted.
